# How to pass java properties for sqoop import job

Tags: sqoop

When using sqoop import is possible to pass java properties.
In my case, I need to pass

```
-Doraoop.oracle.rac.service.name=myservice
```

together with a `--direct` to use sqoop direct connection to an oracle RAC.

Now I need to create a sqoop job with the same parameter but when I try issuing

```
sqoop job --create myjob -- import -Doraoop.oracle.rac.service.name=myservice --direct --connect...
```

It complains saying

```
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -Doraoop.oracle.rac.service.name=myservice
....
```

Wherever I put the `-D` it doesn't work while with the straight sqoop import it works.

It works only in the following way

```
sqoop job -Doraoop.oracle.rac.service.name=myservice --create myjob -- import ...
```

but in this way, the property is passed to the current execution and not to the subsequent job execution.

Is there a way to pass java properties through `-D` to a `sqoop job --create myjob -- import` command?

Trying with sqoop 1.4.6 on cdh 5.5

Answer (score 1):

As per Sqoop [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_6),

Syntax for sqoop job command:

```
sqoop job (generic-args) (job-args) [-- [subtool-name] (subtool-args)]
```

Now `-D`is **generic-arg** and `--create myjob` is **job-arg**

So you have to use command like :

```
sqoop job -Doraoop.oracle.rac.service.name=myservice --create myjob ....
```

For current and all subsequent job execution, it should behave in the same manner.

Inspect the configuration of the job using:

```
sqoop job --show myjob
```

Check if you find any difference in first execution and subsequent execution.